# Navigating many2many relationships in both directions

Tags: django

I'm trying to understand how Django returns columns from foreign keys, particularly the m2m situation, easy in SQL but I'm trying to get into Django.

In this example I have 3 models, `Sample` which has a m2m with `Container`

and `Location` which has a 1-to-many with `Container`.

Scenario 1a: From the Sample table get the Containers that sample is in(return sample_number and container_name).

Scenario 1b: From the Container get the related Samples (return container_number and sample_number).

Scenario 2a: From the Location model get the containers (location_name and container_names).

Scenario 2b: From the Container model get the location (Container_name and location_name).

Hopefully this will serve as a good overall reference for others.

```
# models.py
class Location(models.Model):
    location_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sample_number = models.IntegerField()

class Container(models.Model): #like a friend
    container_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    container_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, db_column='location_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name = 'location')
    samples = models.ManyToManyField('Sample', through='ContainerSamples', related_name='containers')

# views.py - Implements a filter
def detailcontainer(request, container_id):
    container = get_object_or_404(Container, pk=container_id)
    samples = container.samples.all()
    container_contents = container.samples.all()
    unassigned_samples = Sample.objects.all()

    qs = Sample.objects.all()

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'container':container,
        'container_contents': container_contents,
        'unassigned_samples': unassigned_samples,
    }
    return render(request, 'container/detailcontainer.html', context)

# templates

{% for unassigned in unassigned_samples %}

# 1a [solved]
{% for unassigned in unassigned_samples %}
  {{ unassigned.sample_number }}
  {% for container in unassigned.containers.all %}
    {{ container.location_id }}.{{ container.container_name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

# 1b
{{ unassigned.____________ }} # the container_name
{{ unassigned.____________ }} # the related samples (sample_number)

# 2a
{{ unassigned.____________ }} # the location_name
{{ unassigned.____________ }} # the related container names (container_name)

# 2b
{{ unassigned.____________ }} # the container_name
{{ unassigned.____________ }} # the location_name

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed this part of the documentation yet? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ It provides a good description of how to use `ManyToManyField`. Scroll down to the part "Article objects have access to their related Publication objects:"

Comment: Hi yes I looked at that first, but I couldn't understand it in the context of a view/template. I tried Sample.container_set in shell which gets me the m2m_descriptor but I can't find the container_name attribute.

Comment: I've added a solution fot 1a, please comment if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

> Scenario 1a: From the Sample table get the Containers that sample is in(return sample_number and container_name).

```
container_set = sample.containers.all()
for container in container_set:
    print([container.container_name, sample.sample_name])
```

Scenario 1b: From the Container get the related Samples (return container_number and sample_number).

```
sample_set = container.samples.all()
for sample in sample_set:
    print([sample.sample_number, container.container_number])
```

> Scenario 2a: From the Location model get the containers (location_name and container_names).

```
container_set = location.location.all() # You have Container.location_id.related_name = 'location', I don't know why.
for container in container_set:
    print([location.location_name, container.container_name])
```

> Scenario 2b: From the Container model get the location (Container_name and location_name).

```
print([container.container_name, container.location_id.location_name])
```

Also your models should be written as follows:

```
# models.py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Sample(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Container(models.Model): #like a friend
    container = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name='containers')
    samples = models.ManyToManyField(Sample, through='ContainerSamples', related_name='containers')
```

If you're using the same definition for the autofield on the models, there' no reason to add it. When you're defining properties on a model such as a name, you shouldn't prefix it with the model name. It should be understood that it's the model's name. And finally `related_name` is the field on the referenced model for the relationship to traverse back to the current model.